# LibreOffice writer reverts date field to local format

Tags: libreoffice, localization

I have a date field in my footer and I would like it to be shown in ISO 8601 date format and not the local format.
I use

> right click -> Edit Fields... -> Format

to change it and I saved my document, but when I open it the next time it is reverted to the local format.

I am using LibreOffice 6.4.3.2 on Ubuntu 20.04

Please let me know how I can prevent LibreOffice writer from reverting my date format to local format and always keep it in ISO 8601.

Comment: I can not reproduce the problem you are describing on Libreoffice 6.4.4.2 (flatpak). It would be helpful to include the version of Libreoffice and Ubuntu you are using. If the problem persists on an up-to-date vesion of Libreoffice, I would suggest to report a bug on launchpad if you use the version that came with Ubuntu or https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/ if you use a version packaged by the document foundation and attach the offending file (after depersonalizing it).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I could not reproduce it in a new empty document either, so it seems that it is somehow related to my particular document, perhaps some "always revert to localization" document settings somewhere, but where?